# Transparent download of arbitrary files from external domain in PHP

Tags: php

I have two websites, `a.com` and `b.com`. The user navigates `a.com` and should know nothing about `b.com`. But `b.com` hosts some files (PDF, Images, doc, xls) that I would like to serve from `a.com`.

Because I can't just put a link to `b.com/file.pdf`, I need to have a PHP script on `a.com/download.php?q=file.pdf` that pulls the file from `b.com` and sends it to the user agent as if it was a download from `a.com`.

As I said, the whole point is to leave the users of `a.com` unaware of the fact that the files come from `b.com`.

What is the best tool to achive this setup? `file_get_contents`, `curl`, `fread`/`fwrite`? What about the HTTP headers I have to send to the user? I appreciate any pointers to existing solutions.

Comment: [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), because it's a passthru function; but you'll still have to send the appropriate headers whatever you do

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll take it as an answer if you care to post.